# on option select, show/hide table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bootstrap-select

I would like to show/hide a table row based on the options selected in the select box.

**HTML:**

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-selected-text-format="count" data-done-button="true" multiple="" title="Codes">
    <option>A</option>
    <option selected>B</option>
    <option selected>C</option>
    <option selected>K</option>
    <option>X</option>
    <option selected>Y</option>
</select>
<hr>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Codes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="" data-codes="A B C">
            <td>John</td>
            <td>A B C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-disabled" data-codes="A X">
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>A X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="" data-codes="Y C K">
            <td>Paul</td>
            <td>Y C K</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  margin: 30px;  
}

.row-disabled {
  opacity: 0.2;  
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$('select').selectpicker();

$(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  });
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/np3ev91x/

In the fiddle above, the `A` and `X` options are not selected, so the line that has both `A` and `X` receive the class `row-disabled` to change the opacity. If `A` and `X` is selected again, the line should lose the class `row-disabled`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for any codes. with the use of classes and the pre-existing data-codes tag, you can generalize the disabling and enabling of rows as shown below.

```js
$('select').selectpicker();

$('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
  var list = []; 
  $('.selectpicker :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
    list[i] = $(selected).text();
  });

 $('.item').each(function() {
    if ($(this).data('codes').length > 0) {
      var codes = $(this).data('codes').split(" ");

      if (containsAll(codes, list)) {
        $(this).removeClass('row-disabled');    
      }
      else if (containsNone(codes, list)) {
        $(this).addClass('row-disabled');    
      }
    }
    else {
      $(this).removeClass('row-disabled');
    }   
  });
});
  
function containsAll(needles, haystack){ 
  for(var i = 0 , len = needles.length; i < len; i++){
     if($.inArray(needles[i], haystack) == -1) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function containsNone(needles, haystack){ 
  for(var i = 0 , len = needles.length; i < len; i++){
     if($.inArray(needles[i], haystack) != -1) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 30px;  
}

.row-disabled {
  opacity: 0.2;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="selectpicker" data-selected-text-format="count" data-done-button="true" multiple="" title="Codes">
    <option>A</option>
    <option selected>B</option>
    <option selected>C</option>
    <option selected>K</option>
    <option>X</option>
    <option selected>Y</option>
</select>
<hr>
<table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Codes</th>
 </tr>
  </thead>
 <tr class="item row-disabled" data-codes="A B C">
  <td>John</td>
  <td>A B C</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="item row-disabled" data-codes="A X">
  <td>Mary</td>
  <td>A X</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="item" data-codes="Y C K">
  <td>Paul</td>
  <td>Y C K</td>
 </tr>
  <tr class="item" data-codes="">
  <td>Andy</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can this work with all the codes from the tr? I mean, in the first tr, the line should be alpha if A and B and C was unselected. Thanks again.

Comment: @Khrys, it does work with all the codes. ABC should be faded since A is not selected initially. If you deselect Y, then the last line will fade out

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a way to do it as a group... So the first row should only be faded if A B and C is unchecked and vice-versa. Thanks again

Comment: @Khrys oh so, do you mean that the rows are only faded if all of the options are not selected? (and if one or more of the options are selected, then the row shows?)

Comment: Yes. A row should only be visible if all the codes from that row are checked, and the same for faded (only if all the codes from that row are unchecked). I am sorry, I wasn't clear enough. Thanks for your time.

Comment: PS: Your code is working this way with cheking, but for uncheck it is disabling the row if I uncheck one of the codes.

Comment: Example: Working: Uncheck All; Check A and Check X (the second row lights up). Not Working: In the condition above, uncheck A (the row faded, but should only fade when A and X is unchecked). Thanks again

Comment: @Khrys, ohhh i see. i just edited the demo. can you check again to see if that's the functionality you're going for?

Comment: Amazing. Worked like a charm. I just remember one case, for example if there is no codes the line should not enter in the if, it should always be visible. I put a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8vwn2m89/6/. Sorry for not mention this since the start, my bad. Thanks again.

Comment: @Khrys i think my most recent change should address that new requirement.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Sorry to came here again. But, can you share the code that do not action if has all? Instead if has only one value the class should be applied/removed. Thanks.

Comment: @Khrys i can try (but I'm confused as to what you want). can you let me know what functionality you want (give examples like you did before)? and I can see what I can do with the code

Answer (score 1):

You have to `bind` a change event handler to you select element.

The method  `every()` tests whether all elements in the array does not exist in the selected value.

```
$('select').selectpicker().on('changed.bs.select',function(){
  var array=$(this).val();
  $('table tbody tr').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('row-disabled');
        var array2=$(this).find('td').eq(1).text().split(' ');
        if(array2.every(elem=>array.indexOf(elem)!=-1)){
                $(this).removeClass('row-disabled');
        }
  });
}).trigger('change');
```

Here is [working solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/8vwn2m89/5/)

Comment: Since OP is using bootstrap-select, I would use their own change event : changed.bs.select https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/

Comment: Thanks, this works on select remove, but when I try to check again, the first select already remove the class. Can the addClass has the same behavior, I mean, only if all the codes from that tr are checked. Thanks again

Comment: @Khrys, have a look now.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai, Thanks but I am afraid to say it is not working. Example: check all options, after uncheck option A. 2 tr get opacity, but should only get opacity if all codes from data-codes are unchecked. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

a solution with some test :

in your JS :

```
    $('select').selectpicker();

$(".selectpicker").change(function () {
    var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    if(selectedText.indexOf("A")!=-1 && selectedText.indexOf("X")!=-1){
                $('*[data-codes="A X"]').removeClass("row-disabled");
    }
    else {
        $('*[data-codes="A X"]').addClass("row-disabled");
    }
});
```

and the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8vwn2m89/1/